# user_exists function using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I';m working on changing my code from using MySQL to MySQLi, and its all *seemed* to be going fine, but I hit a bit of a wall, I'm currently stuck on changing over my function **user_exists** and I have tried looking into different reason why and what's going wrong but it seems to be the query, i did  **var_dump($result)** and got the response **NULL** and was told that its down to my query then, so i tried an sql search on phpmyadmin and got a result so im thinking its down to me binding *$username* to the *?* as the errors i get is of that it cannot find the username im trying to log in with.

```
function user_exists($username) {
$db = $GLOBALS['db'];
$username = trim($username);
//sql
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?";
//Prepare
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
//Bind
$result->bind_param('s', $username);
//execute
$result->execute();
//Bind-Results - the 2 codes below are noted out cause im not sure they are needed but have tried with and without them
//$result->bind_result($user_id);
//$result->fetch();

if (false === $result) {
   return false;
}
return ($result->num_rows === 1);
}
```

i can provide the code to my signin.php but im not sure it would be useful as it all worked before i started changing the function.

if someone could point out what, where and why its not working, can you please explain so i can understand so Im good for the future and maybe able to help others out.

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Do `if (!$result) echo $db->error;` right after the `prepare()` call.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski nothing comes up, its really baffling me, i thought i was finally understanding all this mysqli stuff, preparing and binding and what not. cause the function is on its own page, im thinking of just doing the function on the signin.php page itself, see if that cuts out anything that myabe making $username not actually come up

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned up and displaying? Something else may have happened earlier.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: yee i do, what i did was just chaging it to if($result) echo 'working'; and that did come up so something must be working? and when i tried to echo $result i get the error Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string .. so that means what is passing through?

Comment: Do you not need to call `$result->store_result();` before checking row count? Been a while since I've done this without PDO...

Comment: @miken32 ill be honest i dont know, i will try it though, im only just learning this stuff so i know things but not alot. i did print_r($result) just after prepare and this is the result i got ...mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 ) ...so its not finding what is needed in the database is it?

Comment: @miken32 Yes you are right. Reason number 47c MySQLi has a crazy and confusing API. See http://us1.php.net/mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$result->store_result()` before checking the number of rows. [`mysqli_stmt::store_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) will load the result set from the prepared statement so you can access results and properties.

EDIT: This is sort of how I would do it though (untested):

```
function user_exists($username) {
    global $db;

    //sql
    $sql = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?";
    //Prepare
    if (!($result = $db->prepare($sql)) return false;
    //Bind
    if (!$result->bind_param('s', trim($username))) return false;
    //execute
    if (!$result->execute()) return false;
    //Bind-Results
    $result->bind_result($user_id);
    $result->fetch();
    $result->close();

    return $user_id ?: false;
}
```

Comment: so i added what you suggested but all it has done is any username/password combo to log in

Comment: That's because you're doing `SELECT COUNT(user_id)` which will always return a row. Just `SELECT user_id` instead.

Comment: ok ill change that now, in the mean time, i found this online and it apparantly worked for that person, would it work or would i be best sticking to how i currently have it and fixing that instead ?...
function user_exists($username,$db) {
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username= ?";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param('s', $username);
$result->execute();
$result->fetch_row();
return ($result[0] == 1) ? true : false;
}

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference either way; either you read the count or you check the number of rows. I would always prefer a function to return a useful value, if I were doing this myself I would have it return the user_id.

Comment: i got this parse error: when running your suggestion, but  your suggestions did solve the issue so thanks i will mark as answered

Comment: If you're using an old version of PHP, try `return empty($user_id) ? false : $user_id;` The shorthand ternary operator was added in 5.4 I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my **user_exist()** function ended up

```
function user_exists($username) {
$db = $GLOBALS['db'];

//sql
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?";
//Prepare
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
//Bind
$result->bind_param('s', $username);
//execute
$result->execute();
//store result
$result->store_result();

if (false === $result) {
   return false;
}
return ($result->num_rows === 1);
}
```

I hope this will help someone. But if any of the code shouldn't be there, i apologise in advance, the code was there for a reason at one point but as im learning all this still, no one advised me that it shouldnt be there.. hope it helps